# Reshaping a Numpy Array into lexicographical list of cubes of shape (n, n, n)

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

In order to understand what I'm trying to achieve let's imagine an ndarray `a` with shape `(8,8,8)` from which I lexicographically take blocks of shape `(4,4,4)`. So while iterating through such blocks the indexes would look as follows:

```
0: a[0:4, 0:4, 0:4]  
1: a[0:4, 0:4, 4:8]  
2: a[0:4, 4:8, 0:4]  
3: a[0:4, 4:8, 4:8]  
4: a[4:8, 0:4, 0:4]  
5: a[4:8, 0:4, 4:8]  
6: a[4:8, 4:8, 0:4]  
7: a[4:8, 4:8, 4:8]
```

It is these blocks of data which I'm trying to access. Obviously, this can be described by using an expression which converts the current iteration to the corresponding indexes. An example of that is given below.

```
a = np.ones((8,8,8))
f = 4

length = round(a.shape[0] * a.shape[1] * a.shape[2] / f**3)

x = a.shape[0] / f
y = a.shape[1] / f
z = a.shape[2] / f

for i in range(length):
    print(f"{i}: {round((int(i/(z*y))%x)*f)}:{round(f+(int(i/(z*y))%x)*f)}, {round((int(i/z)%y)*f)}:{round(f+(int(i/z)%y)*f)}, {round((i%z)*f)}:{round(f+(i%z)*f)}")
```

My apologies for having to do that to your eyes but it generates the following output:

```
0: 0:4, 0:4, 0:4
1: 0:4, 0:4, 4:8
2: 0:4, 4:8, 0:4
3: 0:4, 4:8, 4:8
4: 4:8, 0:4, 0:4
5: 4:8, 0:4, 4:8
6: 4:8, 4:8, 0:4
7: 4:8, 4:8, 4:8
```

So this does actually generate the right indexes, but it only allows you to access multiple blocks at once if they have the same index in the 0th and 1st axis, so no wrapping around. Ideally I would reshape this whole ndarray into an ndarray `b` with shape `(4, 4, 32)` and be ordered in such a way that `b[:, :, :4]` would return `a[0:4, 0:4, 0:4]`, `b[:, :, 4:12]` returns an ndarray of shape `(4, 4, 8)` which contain `a[0:4, 0:4, 4:8]` and `a[0:4, 4:8, 0:4]` etc. I want this to be as fast as possible, so ideally, I keep the memory layout and just change the view on the array.
Lastly, if it helps to think about this conceptually, this is basically a variant of the `ndarray.flatten()` method but using blocks of shape `(4, 4, 4)` as "atomic size" if you will.

Hope this makes it clear enough!

Comment: The stacking is important. When you say `(4, 4, 8) which contain a[0:4, 0:4, 4:8] and a[0:4, 4:8, 0:4]`, would the stacking be vertical or horizontal or maybe some other way?

Comment: Please provide a small input/desired output. I would suggest using `a=np.arange(64).reshape(4,4,4)` and `f=2` and output for us to understand better. Thank you.

Comment: So in this specific example, given ```b``` with shape ```(4, 4, 8)```, ```b[:, :, 4:8] == a[0:4, 0:4, 4:8]``` and ```b[: , :, 8:12] == a[0:4, 4:8, 0:4]```. This would extend to ```b[:, :, 12:16] == a[0:4, 4:8, 4:8]```. important is that these blocks of shape ```(4, 4, 4)``` stay equivalent in both representations. Hope that helps!

Comment: @SvenHendrikx Please checkout the edit on the post I made to see if that is what you are looking for. Thank you.

Comment: @Ehsan Yes, the first proposed solution uses a rolling window implementation so that's not exactly what I was looking for, but the edit with PaulPanzer's suggestion is exactly what I needed, thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bit unclear what you want as output. Are you looking for this:

```
from skimage.util.shape import view_as_windows
b = view_as_windows(a,(f,f,f),f).reshape(-1,f,f,f).transpose(1,2,3,0).reshape(f,f,-1)
```

suggested by @Paul with similar result (I prefer this answer in fact):

```
N = 8
b = a.reshape(2,N//2,2,N//2,N).transpose(1,3,0,2,4).reshape(N//2,N//2,N*4)
```

output:

```
print(np.array_equal(b[:, :, 4:8],a[0:4, 0:4, 4:8]))
#True
print(np.array_equal(b[:, :, 8:12],a[0:4, 4:8, 0:4]))
#True
print(np.array_equal(b[:, :, 12:16],a[0:4, 4:8, 4:8]))
#True
```

Comment: I don't think you need `view_as_windows` here. A simple `reshape` should suffice; `b = a.reshape(2,N//2,2,N//2,N).transpose(1,3,0,2,4).reshape(N//2,N//2,N*4)`

Comment: @PaulPanzer That is true. I added it to the post. Originally was not sure what OP is looking for. Thank you.

Comment: isnt the axes numbering in `transpose()` wrong? should'nt it be `(0, 2, 4, 1, 3)`

Comment: @Hammad No, the transpose is what OP asked for. Please checkout the checks on array at the end of the post that confirms it.

Comment: @PaulPanzer That's exactly what I was looking for, great suggestion!

Comment: I've run into some problems generalizing this to arbitrary input and query shapes, but I thought since it's actually a follow up question I've created a new post: <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62997697/iteration-through-a-3d-array-using-a-2d-query-window-by-using-numpy-transpose/62997750?noredirect=1#comment111404914_62997750>. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score -1):

```
def flatten_by(arr, atomic_size):
    a, b, c = arr.shape
    x, y, z = atomic_size
    
    r = arr.reshape([a//x, x, b//y, y, c//z, z])
    r = r.transpose([0, 2, 4, 1, 3, 5])
    r = r.reshape([-1, x, y, z])
    
    return r
```

```
flatten_by(arr, [4,4,4]).shape

>>>   (8, 4, 4, 4)
```

> EDIT:

the function applies C-style flattening to the array, as shown below

> NOTE:
> this method and @Ehsan's method both produce "copies" NOT "views", im looking into it and would update the answer when if i find a solution

```
flattened = flatten_by(arr, [4,4,4])

required = np.array([
    arr[0:4, 0:4, 0:4],
    arr[0:4, 0:4, 4:8],  
    arr[0:4, 4:8, 0:4],  
    arr[0:4, 4:8, 4:8],  
    arr[4:8, 0:4, 0:4],  
    arr[4:8, 0:4, 4:8],  
    arr[4:8, 4:8, 0:4],  
    arr[4:8, 4:8, 4:8],  
])
```

```
np.array_equal(required, flattened)

>>> True
```

Comment: This answer is already posted below. Plus the transpose is incorrect according to what OP wants. To understand better, check it with `print(np.array_equal(b[:, :, 12:16],a[0:4, 4:8, 4:8]))` per OP's request on question. Thank you.

Comment: @Ehsan i've also added checks, this one holds too

Comment: Thank you for checking it. Seems that those are just the required chunks though. Please refer to the last part of the question or comments section on how the OP wants the final output (shape) to be, unless I am missing sth.