# Iteration through a 3D array using a 2D query window by using Numpy transpose

Tags: python, numpy

This question is a generalized version of a question which I have asked before:
[Reshaping a Numpy Array into lexicographical list of cubes of shape (n, n, n)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62822637/reshaping-a-numpy-array-into-lexicographical-list-of-cubes-of-shape-n-n-n)

The question is, given an nd-array of shape `(x, y, z)` and a query window `(p, q)`, with the restriction that `x % p == 0` and `y % q == 0`, how do I transpose the matrix in such a way that it has shape `(p, q, -1)` and maintains the ordering proposed in the original question. The idea is that I can quickly take slices of a specific shape instead of having to iterate to the relevant indices.

In the original post, this answer was proposed:

```
N = 4
a = np.arange(N**3).reshape(N,N,N)

b = a.reshape(2,N//2,2,N//2,N).transpose(1,3,0,2,4).reshape(N//2,N//2,N*4)
```

with output:

```
print(b):

[[[ 0  1  2  3  8  9 10 11 32 33 34 35 40 41 42 43]
  [ 4  5  6  7 12 13 14 15 36 37 38 39 44 45 46 47]]

 [[16 17 18 19 24 25 26 27 48 49 50 51 56 57 58 59]
  [20 21 22 23 28 29 30 31 52 53 54 55 60 61 62 63]]]
```

This would correspond to input shape `(4, 4, 4)`, query shape `(2, 2)` and output shape `(2, 2, -1)`.
The accepted answer in the original question is close to what I need, but its output shape is dependent on the shape of the nd-array. That is not the behavior that I am looking for as I'd like to use any query shape `(p, q)` for any input shape `(x, y, z)`.
I am not very proficient in using Numpy transpose to implement these kinds of operations (I have tried to use this answer and generalize its myself without success), so it would be greatly appreciated if, when answered, the answer could be supplemented with a bit of an explanation about the approach which the answerer took or point to some resources which could help me out with this!

Hope that makes it clear!

Answer (score 0):

It can be <del>just a simple modification</del> modified, think `(p,q) = (2,2)` in this case. So something like this:

```
a.reshape(p, x//p, q, y//q, -1).transpose(3,1,2,0,4).reshape(p,q,-1)
```

Comment: ```b = a.reshape(p, x//p, q, x//q, -1).transpose(1,3,0,2,4).reshape(p,q,-1)``` gives the desired result for input shape ```(4, 4, 4)```, but it doesn't with input shape ```(8, 8, 8)```. The idea is that these blocks of shape ```(2,2,1``` which get when querying ```b[:, :, i]``` are ordered lexicographically

Comment: `transpose(1,3,0,2,4)` or `transpose(0,2,1,3,4)`?

Comment: more specifically: for input shape ```(4, 4, 4)``` and query shape ```(p, q) = (2, 2)```, the output is: 
```[[[ 0  1] [ 4  5]] [[16 17] [20 21]]]```
while the output for input shape (8, 8, 8) should be:
```[[[ 0  1] [ 8  9]] [[64 65] [72 73]]]```

Comment: ```transpose(1,3,0,2,4)```, you can see an explanation about this in the original question

Comment: @SvenHendrikx see updated answer. It should be `3,1,2,0` not `1,3,0,2`.